# Regex get nth value separated with slash

Tags: c#, regex

I have a universal regex code where it uses `Groups[1]` value to extract the result. It's easy to extract SN and Ref by just giving a `sn=(.*?)\.` pattern. But it's so difficult to get for example, `PKSC` and `V928`. I have to use `Groups[1]` because users who use this application can choose their own value to display. It can be `NC339` or `PKXC`.

```
//var source = "SN=1395939213.#variable/OGT84/PKXC/Undetermined.Thank You@{customer}"
//sometimes like this
var source = "SN=8029758034.Ref=BFO7Y95B3KN5#resolved/NC339/V928/ClearenceBBF.Brief@{supervisor}/verified"

var value = Regex.Match(source, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: Why are you using REGEX for something so trivial?  Just use the String Split method which is a lot more efficient than REGEX.

Comment: Because I also need to extract SN and `{supervisor}/verified`

Comment: Then use regex after the split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:[^/]*/){2}([^/]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F42VFZ/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:[^/]*/){2}` - two occurrences of any chars other than `/` and then a `/`
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `/`.

Comment: What's the different between your answer and this `(?:.*?/){3}(.[^/]*)`

Comment: @derodevil There are a lot of differences, see [your regex demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/F42VFZ/2). Note the main one is `.` matches any char other than a newline. When you have delimited strings, do not use `.` unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
           string pattern = @"SN=(?'sn'\d+).*\{(?'supervisor'[^}]+)";
            string input = "SN=1395939213.#variable/OGT84/PKXC/Undetermined.Thank You@{customer}";
            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            string sn = match.Groups["sn"].Value;
            string supervisor = match.Groups["supervisor"].Value;
```